# Spring 3.1 ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource and Apache Tiles 2.2.2

Tags: spring-mvc, internationalization, jstl, servlet-3.0, tiles2

What seemed to be a simple task has turned out to be a few hours of suffering.
I am building a Spring 3.1 MVC application on the JavaEE 6 and Servlet 3.0.1 api without a web.xml file. I have a  *WebMvcConfiguration* class like this fragment:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "be.collectortools.collectorsite")
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

@Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSourceBean() {
        String[] basenames = {"classpath:messages"};

        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resourceBundle = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        resourceBundle.setBasenames(basenames);
        resourceBundle.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resourceBundle;
    }
}
```

I have successfully setup Apache Tiles 2.2.2 together with 2 basic controllers.
Now I would like to add ResourceBundles to the working Spring/Tiles application and I can't get them to work.

After searching I found some this that might go wrong:

- Do I use *fmt:message key="application.header"* or should I use *spring:message code="application.header"* in my JSP pages? The first ignores not found values the second throws errors.
- I use *ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource* which should be 'better' or at least newer then *ResourceBundleMessageSource* is this ok?
- *ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource* loads files from more locations so I have specified *classpath:*
- I placed the messages.properties file in the src/main/resources folder
- Is it still correct that, when not adding a locale to the end of a bundle's name, this is used as a (default) fallback? Either way adding the "en_US" locale doesn't help.

**The error**:

```
root cause

javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'application.header' for locale 'en_US'.
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doStartTagInternal(MessageTag.java:184)
```

also the war file is not being run inside Eclipse I deploy it manually to my local tomcat 7.0.23. This also allows me to see the deployed file structure more easily and gives me better control.

I have no clue what is I am doing wrong any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MessageSource bean has to be named `messageSource` not `messageSourceBean` - if you change your @Bean to the following it should resolve the messages correctly:

```
@Bean
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    String[] basenames = {"classpath:messages"};

    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resourceBundle = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    resourceBundle.setBasenames(basenames);
    resourceBundle.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return resourceBundle;
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that the name for the method acctualy makes a difference. I'll check this tonight. This doesn't apply to the other methods for eg. the view resolver soo I didn't check this.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this simple detail! I just wander why it makes a difference here, but not for eg. tilesViewResolverBean. I will look into it later on.